# [C++]Program terminating without explanation

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
cout << "Welcome to your personal seat booking program." << endl;
cout << "Please follow the instructions to book your seat." << endl << endl;
cout << "Would you like a seat by the window? (true/false)" << endl;
cin >> userInputWindow;
if (userInputWindow = true)
{

}
else if (userInputWindow = false)
{

}

cout << "Would you like a seat with a table? (true/false)" << endl;
cin >> userInputTable;
if (userInputTable = true)
{

}
else if (userInputTable = false)
{

}

cout << "Would you like to be seated in First Class? (true/false)" << endl;
cin >> userInputClass;
if (userInputClass = true)
{

}
else if (userInputClass = false)
{

}

cout << "Do you need Ease-Of-Access seating? (true/false)" << endl;
cin >> userInputAccess;
if (userInputAccess = true)
{

}
else if (userInputAccess = false)
{

}

cout << "Do you need a forward facing seat? (true/false)" << endl;
cin >> userInputForward;
if (userInputForward = true)
{

}
else if (userInputForward = false)
{

}
```

When I run this, it asks me for input for the first `cin` statement, but then skips through the rest of the script, even skipping the `system("PAUSE")` I have at the end. Any reason for this? I'm at a loss, but I'm very new to programming, and having difficulty.
Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you step through your code using a debugger? (F10 in Visual Studio, and F10 again to keep stepping through.) Aside: `userInputWindow = true` should be `userInputWindow == true`, otherwise you're assigning to the variable and the `if` will always be entered...

Comment: Source of the problem: by default input stream expects 1 or 0 when asked to read boolean variable, not some letters.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: Alright, I've changed all the if statement parameters to `==`, changed all the `<< endl;` to `\n`, still the same problem ):  When I use the debugger, it steps through everything perfectly, but skips the `cin` statements, not stopping for user input.

Answer (score 0):

What happened is, at the first selection if and else if, since there is nothing inside if and if else, the program will terminate whether user enter true or false. What selection if and else if does is that it is like an intercept, you whether turn left or turn right(choose go to the first if, or the second if else), and keep going until the road ends(program terminates). Therefore there is no explanation when your program ends, since there is no syntax errors that needs to be explained. 
I assume you want the program to keep asking questions when user enter "true" with some questions.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_if_else_statement.htm

```
int main()
{
cout << "Welcome to your personal seat booking program." << endl;
cout << "Please follow the instructions to book your seat." << endl << endl;
cout << "Would you like a seat by the window? (true/false)" << endl;
cin >> userInputWindow;
if (userInputWindow == true)
{

cout << "Would you like a seat with a table? (true/false)" << endl;
cin >> userInputTable;
if (userInputTable == true)
{
cout << "Would you like to be seated in First Class? (true/false)" << endl;
cin >> userInputClass;
if (userInputClass == true)
{
cout << "Do you need Ease-Of-Access seating? (true/false)" << endl;
cin >> userInputAccess;
if (userInputAccess == true)
{   
cout << "Do you need a forward facing seat? (true/false)" << endl;
cin >> userInputForward;
if (userInputForward == true)
{
cout << "Program terminated";
}
else if (userInputForward == false)
{
}
}
else if (userInputAccess == false)
{
}
}
else if (userInputClass == false)
{

}
}
else if (userInputTable == false)
{

}
}
else if (userInputWindow == false)
{

}
```

This will keep the program going if you keep entering true, don't know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: This has been quite helpful, but I'm looking for the program to simply take the users preferences, whether true OR false, not just continue the code if they only enter true. I tried `\* *\` the if statements out, still the same problem.